# Problems with Japanese WordNet

Tags: java, wordnet

I'm a novice with JWNL and I'm trying to use "Japanese Wordnet and English WordNet in an sqlite3 database" which can be obtained from the following link:
http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/wnja/index.en.html

I don't quite understand how to make a proper "properties.xml" for this wordnet.
Right now, the "properties.xml" is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jwnl_properties language="japanese">
 <version publisher="NIT" number="1.1" language="ja"/>
  <dictionary class="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.DatabaseBackedDictionary">
    <param name="dictionary_element_factory" 
  value="net.didion.jwnl.princeton.data.PrincetonWN17FileDictionaryElementFactory"/>
    <param name="file_manager" value="net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.file_manager.FileManagerImpl">
      <param name="file_type" value="net.didion.jwnl.princeton.file.PrincetonRandomAccessDictionaryFile"/>
      <param name="dictionary_path" value="D:\Program Files\Us1\jap_dict"/>
    </param>
  </dictionary>
<resource class="PrincetonResource"/>
```

</jwnl_properties>

When I run the program the exception launches:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "NUMBER_OF_VERB_FRAMES"

Thanks for your time